# Lettrine indents all paragraphs

Tags: lettrine

I am using the lettrine package. The block of text to the right of the capital letter (the number of these lines is defined by the "lines" option, default I guess is two) is indented to accomodate for the capital letter. But the first two lines of each subsequent paragraph are also being indented. Can anyone advise me on how to prevent this subsequent indentation?

I don't know if there is any point to include snippet of code since I have used it twice in the document before, in the exact same way, without this issue. Could it be something to do with the \parskip package?

[image]

```
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\lettrine{H}{ere} Here  Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here

Here  Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here Here 

\section{Drag and Skin Friction Drag}

 Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract 

Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract Abstract 

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

(note in the snippet I all I have changed is the text in first two paragraphs but problem persists)

Referring to this link: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10705 the last comment provided something that works. Basically, adding \parshape=0 before the next paragraph. All the subsequent indentations disappear. Does that make the issue any clearer? I did't need to add this to the previous instances for them to be okay.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I can't reproduce the wrong output. Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: Your MWE works fine if I use it with book class.

Comment: It worked fine in two previous instances in the file, but for some reason I get this issue on this occasion.

Comment: @HuzKhan Just to clarify things: Do you get the problem with the exact same code as in your question?

Comment: @samcarter yes.

Comment: @HuzKhan Can you add the documentclass you are using to your MWE?

Comment: The issue in the link is due to `quotation`, but your case has nothing similar. If I add `\documentclass{book}` and compile your code, I have no problem at all.